# SurfaceView (camera preview) goes black after screen On/Off

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand interesting thing. I made simple application with SurfaceView and Button. SurfaceView shows camera preview and Button shoot picture. Everything goes good except one moment:

If i press home button, my app goes to background, ok, then i turn screen off/on, then i tap on app icon and my app moves to foreground and everything is correct, i see preview camera again. BUT If i turn screen off/on without moving my app to background, then i see black preview without camera and cant make any pictures.

Please, help, i broke my brain :)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385839/camera-preview-is-completely-black-after-screen-off-screen-on
and there's a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18605746/755804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it possible that the activity is being destroyed and yet the camera is now still "locked" so not even the camera app can show a preview of it?

anyway , you should stop previewing the camera upon onPause (and releasing it upon onDestroy) and resume it when needed.

Comment: I am releasing camera in onPause and opening the camera in onResume. When i turn screen off and on again, the preview is still black. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: kindly write a new thread with this question and show your code.

Comment: I can do this with the API Demos sample project provided with the SDK.

Comment: so you mean they have the same bug there too ?

Comment: Yes, at least on some of my devices. I can go to Graphics > Camera Preview, turn screen off, turn screen on, and the entire screen is black. The camera application somehow gets around this issue.

Comment: any idea to solve this problem？？