# Camera preview is completely black after screen off, screen on

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I'm working with the CameraPreview in the API Demos that comes with the Android SDK. While the camera preview is running, if I turn off my screen and turn it on again, the camera preview is completely black. The device's camera application somehow manages to restore the camera preview, so there must be a way.

Not all devices I've tried exhibit this behavior. I can't confirm, but it seems like the OS version matters.

Comment: same pblm for me, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to release and reacquire the camera in pause/resume.  Here's some code from my CameraView widget:

```
public void onPause(){
    if(camera != null){
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}

public void onResume(){
    //Need to release if we already have one, or we won't get the camera
    if(camera != null){
        camera.release();
        camera = null;          
    }
    try {
        camera = Camera.open(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm using the API Demos. They already acquire/release the camera in onPause and onResume.

Comment: No idea then.  But I do know I had this problem when writing my app, and this is the exact code that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was setContentView() in onResume().

It can be either

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.xxx);
    // ...
}
```

or

```
private View cachedContentView;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    cachedContentView = doCreateContentView(getLayoutInflater());
    // ...
}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(cachedContentView);
    // ...
}
```

Both of them work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Maybe, it isn't the best solution, but it works for me.
In onPause() method restart your camera activity.

```
private boolean isBackPreesed = false;

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

    if (!isBackPreesed) {
        finish();
        Intent restart = new Intent(this, this.getClass());
        startActivity(restart);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        isBackPreesed = true;
    }       
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is release camera in surfaceDestroyed method not in onPause method and restart camera in surfaceCreated method .The result is fine.

Comment: So, how far you think it's answer and not comment?